# VB.NET Ignoring bad references at compilation

Tags: vb.net, deployment, compilation, dependencies

I've got a problem with a program that references a third party ActiveX component that I've been refused permission to distribute.

The AX component is used on some user defined controls which the user can add programatically, which makes isolating them fairly easy.

However, the problem is that if the program is installed on a machine without the third party component then it just crashes, where I would much prefer it to just alert the user to the missing component and then disable the functionality that requires the component.

In the past I've tried adding the reference programatically but have found that this solution doesn't work with this particular control.

Any suggestions as to a strategy that allows the program to run despite missing referenced components would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it throw an exception? What do you mean by "crash"?

Answer (score 0):

You use a launcher app. Deploy both apps. The shortcut you show to the user should start your launcher app. The launcher will first check that all the dependencies are in place, and if so go on to start your app. Otherwise, it will show the user a nicer error message, and perhaps point them to where they can find the missing dependency.

Comment: Yup, that would work, but what I forgot to say was I didn't want to maintain two virtually identical applications, this solution is pretty close to one I've already considered, and its actually my fallback position